# How do I suppress this foreach warning when the function that contains it relies on $_POST data

Tags: php, function, foreach

I have the following code which functions as intended when `$_POST` values are set, however, if no `$_POST` values(IE when the page is first loaded) are set I get `"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in..."` `$_POST` is always going to be empty until the user clicks submit. I have tried `empty()`, `isset()` and now `count()`.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])){

$errors = CheckFormErrors();

    if(count($errors) == 0){
        $data = CleanFormData();
        print_r($data);
    }
}
```

Here is the function being called(not yet complete, but it is working):

```
function CleanFormData(){
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        if($key == 'description'){ continue; }
        if($key == 'file'){ continue; }
        if($key == 'role'){ continue; }

        $_POST[$key] = is_array($key) ? $_POST[$key]: strip_tags($_POST[$key]);
    }
        return $_POST;
}
```

I thought that I could surpress the error by putting it in a conditional statement, evidently that is incorrect. A little help?

Comment: you can `if (!empty($_POST) )` then call your `foreach`

Comment: From your code that doesn't seem possible. You check whether the `submitbtn` index exists in `$_POST` then call `CleanFormData`, So how can `$_POST` not be an array when the  `submitbtn` index exists?

Comment: @JonStirling That is what I don't understand either. You would think that without the submitbtn being set none of that would come into play, but evidently it does as the error pops up on page load.

Comment: @user3154948 Seems more likely that you're calling CleanFormData eleswhere where you don't have the check.

Comment: You can suppress PHP Errors and warnings on the PHP config, But I would try `if(!empty($_POST['submitbtn']))`

Comment: `$_POST[$key] = is_array($key) ? $_POST[$key]: strip_tags($_POST[$key]);` How can a post var key be expected to be an array?

Comment: @Flosculus I am the wrong person to ask, I worked hours on that one line and finally had to come here and try other suggestions until I found one that worked properly. And I passed that one by a couple times because I didn't think it would work myself before finally trying it. I does work though! Maybe someone could break it down for us because I am curious as well.

Comment: @user3154948 Well, `is_array($key)` won't ever pass, it's probably meant to be `is_array($value)`.

Comment: @Flosculus, like I said, wrong person to ask but I can tell you it does exactly what I intended it to do and throws no errors, so I am going with it...lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in comments, you have to check if the superglobal `$_POST` is empty before calling the `foreach` itself (inside the function), not outside the function - this way you don't have to check for `!empty($_POST)` every time you are calling this function.

```
function CleanFormData() {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            // Loops here
        }
    }
    return $_POST;
}
```

Comment: Happy to have been of assistance! :)